# Call function without parameter and parenthesis

Tags: c

In the following code snippet, the main function calls foo function without any parameter and parenthesis. It is strange that this code can be compiled by gcc. I actually check the assembly code and find out that the compiler just ignore this line. So my question is in which situation this kind of code is used? Or the support of gcc is just a coincidence and actually it is totally useless.

```
int foo(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
int main()
{
    foo;      // call foo without parameter and parenthesis
    return 0;
}
```

Its assembly code dumped by objdump -d

```
00000000004004c0 <main>:
  4004c0:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004c1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004c4:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4004c9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004ca:   c3                      retq   
  4004cb:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

Comment: No functions are being called without parentheses here. However, the [REBOL programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REBOL) actually does allow you to call functions without parentheses.

Answer (score 12):

This is no different than having any other type of expression and ignoring its value, like:

```
int main(void)
{
  42;
  return 0;
}
```

there's nothing special, this is *not* calling the function since the function-call operators `()` are not being used. All you're doing is "computing" the functions' address, then ignoring it.

Comment: So then what's the point of doing this? I have run into a piece of code that also does this and can't figure out why.

Comment: @JeffersonHudson I don't think there is any point. Any sane compiler will compile it to nothing, i.e. it will just be ignored since it has no side-effects. It can be remains of debugging, or just an editing mistake perhaps.

Answer (score 7):

The expression `foo` is evaluated (giving the address of the function), and the result is discarded.  Without the `()` operator, the function isn't called.

Comment: `foo` isn't even evaluated. `foo` is merely a human readable name in source code that refers to an address of a function. This address isn't called, so there's isn't yet any "result" to discard

Comment: @Alexander 123 is an expression by C definition, so is foo. Actually anything is an expression and any expression is evaluated. 123 is evaluated as integer number 123, 123L is evaluated as long number 123, foo is evaluated as the function address. I agree that evaluation does not occur at runtime, I understand what you mean. But, theoretically speaking, at compile time, the human readable symbol is evaluated and substituted with its address and then ignored (or simply optimized out of existence). So the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is not getting called, it is just referred (and not assigned to anything).