# C++ returning value from function

Tags: c++, function, return-value

I'm trying to return a value from a function but all it return is the value 1.

It's suppose to have 5 arguments in the `computeCivIndex()`, even if I hard coded the values the output I receive would still be 1.

Why is this so ?

```
float LocationData::computeCivIndex()
{
     civNum1 = 45.0 / 100;
     civNum2 = 20 + 50;
     civNum3 = civNum2 / 200;
     civNum4 = civNum1 - civNum3;
     civNum5 = 5 + 10;


    return civNum;
}

//display data
void LocationData::displaydata()
{
cout << "CIV value: " << computeCivIndex << endl;
}
```

Comment: `civNum` is uninitialized.

Comment: But you're returning `civNum`, not any of the values inside the function...

Comment: What is `civNum` and how is it modified in `computeCivIndex()`? Add relevant code.

Answer (score 5):

You miss `()` in `cout << "CIV value: " << computeCivIndex() << endl;`.
For importance of braces you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881693/call-function-without-parameter-and-parenthesis).

Comment: Some explanation of what is happening without `()` would be nice.

Comment: `civNum` is not being used in function too

Comment: Without the `()`, a pointer to the method is passed to cout (as a void*).

Comment: @xorguy: That doesn't sound right; if it's a non-static member function then that's an invalid use, and even if it is static there's no conversion from `float()` to `void*`.

Comment: @Anton Golov you're right I tried to compile that and the compiler threw an error because it wasn't a static member.

Answer (score 1):

cout << "CIV value: " << **computeCivIndex** << endl;

seems to be printing the value of the function (not the return value). You need to put the function brackets in:

cout << "CIV value: " << **computeCivIndex()** << endl;

Comment: because I have 5 arguments in computeCivIndex so do I need to put in the 5 arguments for the cout?

Comment: err...no :) What I (and also Igor Popov) means is that writing the function name without the brackets does not "call" the function, it merely returns the functions address (i.e. you are printing the value of the function). If you put in brackets at the end of the function then this is the correct syntax to call the function and return the value calculated by the function to the cout.

Comment: Also as others have mentioned, you civNum itself is returned by the function but its value is NEVER changed. You need to assign a new value to this variable before you return it. For example: `civNum = civNum1 + civNum5;`

Answer (score 0):

```
//convert sunType to sunTypePercentage
float LocationData::computeCivIndex(string st, int earth, int moons, float particle, float plasma)
{

    float sunTypePercent;

    if(st == "Type 0")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 80.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type B")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 45.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type A")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 60.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type F")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 75.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type G")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 90.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type K")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 80.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type M")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 70.0;
    }

    // calculate CIV Value
    float civNum,civNum1,civNum2,civNum3,civNum4,civNum5;

    civNum1 = sunTypePercent / 100;
    civNum2 = plasma + particle;
    civNum3 = civNum2 / 200;
    civNum4 = civNum1 - civNum3;
    civNum5 = earth + moons;

    civNum = civNum4 * civNum5;


    return civNum;
}

//display data
void LocationData::displaydata()
{

    cout << "suntype: " << sunType << endl;
    cout << "earth: " << noOfEarthLikePlanets << endl;
    cout << "moons: " << noOfEarthLikeMoons << endl;
    cout << "particle: " << aveParticulateDensity << endl;
    cout <<"density: " << avePlasmaDensity << endl;
    cout << "CIV value: " << computeCivIndex()<< endl;
}
```

This is the actual code which i'm having problem with. For the computeCivIndex() function it is actually a static under the public LocationData class in my LocationData.h file which look something like this.

static float compute CivIndex(string st, int earth, int moons, float particle, float plasma);

so in order to retrieve the value from the function should I do this instead?

cout << "CIV value: " << LocationData.computeCivIndex() << endl;